Gambler's ruin in positive expectation game
The Wikipedia page for gambler's conceit contains the following statement.

Relatedly, gambler's ruin shows that a player with finite resources continuously playing will inevitably go broke against a player with infinite resources in a fair or negative-expectation game. However, this is also true in a positive-expectation game if the player with finite resources continually plays and increases their stakes when winning, but does not reduce them when losing.

What exactly does the last sentence mean, and how to prove it?

Well, as stated, the claim seems false in general.  After all, if you played a game with a guaranteed positive outcome, you wouldn't care that your opponent was immortal.  Perhaps they are making some claim about marginal cases...where the expectation is technically positive but for which there is still a high probability of a loss.  Hard to guess what they had in mind.

Then it might be better to remove this sentence from Wikipedia altogether?

The sentence has been deleted.

As stated it is not always true, but can be true depending on the details.
As an simple example, suppose somebody starts with $1$ token and bet a positive integer number of tokens where winning pays off returning the bet plus $3$ times the bet while the probability of winning is $\frac12$, so the positive expectation is $3 \times \frac12 - 1 \times \frac12=1$ times the amount bet. We might define "going broke" as a stage when they are left with less wealth than their bet size.

If each time the player wins, they multiply their bet size $\times 4$ (in effect betting everything they have every time), then they go broke the first time they lose, and that eventually happens with probability $1$.

If each time the player wins, they increase their bet $+1$ token, then empirically the probability they never go broke is between $25\%$ and $26\%$. (Note they have a $50\%$ chance of going broke on the first bet and a $12.5\%$ chance of going broke on the third bet, $5.25\%$ on the fifth bet, $\approx 0.78\%$ on the seventh, $\approx 1.17\%$ on the eighth, and then it goes down quickly.)


